# Make multiple screenshots with nightmare-screenshot-selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I have a web-page with set of 'li' elements. I need to make screenshots for each 'li' element and save it to a new files.
I'm trying to use nightmare-screenshot-selector for it.
But I get a few files with the same screenshot but with different names (from my array).

Here is my code.

```
const Nightmare     = require('nightmare');
const fs            = require('fs');
const screenshotSelector = require('nightmare-screenshot-selector');
Nightmare.action('screenshotSelector', screenshotSelector);

function savePicture(picture) {
    picture = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'];
    let browser = Nightmare({
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            partition: 'nopersist'
        }
    });
    browser   
        .goto('https://www.google.com')
    picture.forEach(v => {  
        browser   
            .wait(7000)
            .screenshotSelector(`li[class="${v}"]`) 
            .then(function (data) {                 
                fs.writeFileSync(`img/${v}.png`, data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error loading the page', error)
            })
    })
    browser.end();
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the selector to `li .${v}`?

Comment: Are your `<li>`'s "tagged" with like `<li class="v1">first item</li>    <li class="v2">second item</li>` and so on? Because it seems that's what the code is selecting.

Comment: Yes, that's right: <li class="v1">first item</li> <li class="v2">second item</li>. I tried to change to li .${v} and it doesn't work this way: "Selector "li .v1" does not correspond to an element."

Comment: Maybe remove space between li and .v1? So `li.v1`?

Comment: Yes, it works `li.v1` but with the same result as I described before. I think there is a problem with the buffering, Nightmare makes a screenshot only of the first element and save it to the buffer. And I don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted a .end() call, works for me. Slightly modified code, grabs two regions of Google home page:

```
function savePicture(picture) {
    picture = ['div#hplogo', 'div.tsf-p'];
    let browser = Nightmare({
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            partition: 'nopersist'
        }
    });
    browser   
        .goto('https://www.google.com')
    picture.forEach(v => {  
        browser   
            .wait(2000)
            .screenshotSelector(v) 
            .then(function (data) {                 
                fs.writeFileSync(`img/${v}.png`, data)
            })
            .then(()=> {
                browser.end();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error loading the page', error)
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it works with `browser.end();` on other pages on my website. But the problem was with my elements that created using javascript.

Comment: In that case, maybe you need to include some code to replicate the error, such as some JavaScript code to generate the page instead of www.google.com in the example.